# How to validate JWT token in php

Tags: php, jwt, access-token

I am new to `JWT`. I'll straight jump to my question.

I want to use `JWT` in my application. I am at an early stage of analyzing on how can I use it and then suddenly I was stuck on how will I validate or re-verify the `JWT token` sent in `header` with each `API request`, with the original `JWT token` generated when the login was done successfully.

Would that mean I will have to store the originally generated `JWT token` somewhere(like `database` or `cookie` or `php sessions`) and retrieve them every time for comparing with the sent `JWT token`. Or is there any other way to do that.

Please help me in clearing this doubt and learning something new.

Comment: Sessions or cookies should be fine. Normally. when I work with `JWT`s with javascript, I'll store it in `Local Storage`.

Comment: That's correct sir. But how would I validate that token on server side when sent with an api call?

Comment: Having done this before myself - Just head over to GitHub and search `JWT`.  You should be able to find one that works and has a license that fits with your project. (If I'm understanding the question in your comment above - you're set on a way to receive it, and just wanting a pointer on how to actually do the verify step.)

Comment: https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 0):

Validation on serverside is done by comparing signature with newly created hash on the server from the payload.

something like

```
public function verify($message, $signature, $key)
{
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $key, true);
    return hash_equals($hash, $signature) ? true : false;
}
```

where message is something like

```
list($headb64, $bodyb64, $cryptob64) = explode('.', $token);
    
$headerRaw = static::urlsafeB64Decode($headb64);
$bodyRaw   = static::urlsafeB64Decode($bodyb64);
$cryptoRaw = static::urlsafeB64Decode($cryptob64);

$valid = $this->verify( "{$headb64}.{$bodyb64}", $cryptoRaw );
```

but I advice you to look into existing packages like
https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

They keep everything up to par.